# Is it possible to assign a struct an array from a 2D array

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I can't figure out how to quickly initialize a bunch of structs. I'm getting stuck on needing to assign them a character array. The code is as follows:

```
typedef struct {
    char name[5];
} s;

s * buildS() {    
    char names[2][5] = { "name", "foo"};
    s stru[2];

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        s tmp;
        tmp.name = names + i;
        stru[i] = tmp;
    }

    return stru;
}
```

The `s.name = names + 1;` line is where the error appears:

`error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'char[5]' from type 'char (*)[5]'`

What am I missing here? Can I assign an internal array to a struct's array field?

Edit: fixed to crappy syntax in the code, my bad

Comment: `strncpy(s.name, &names[i], strlen(names[i]));`?

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641473/initialize-static-array-of-structs-in-c

Comment: s is type........

Comment: Sorry, there's a few errors in the code, I just wanted to put down the general idea of what I was trying to do. It isn't literally what I pasted

Comment: Array has allocated memory. You can't point it to another location.

Comment: Try Fortran....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're trying to split the array containing names into two structs.

To do that based on what you have done :

Include `<string.h>`

Then change :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        s tmp;
        s.name = names + i;
    }
```

To :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
       strcpy(stru[i].name, names[i]);
}
```